# How to validate Input type number in vuejs- if input has invalid number

Tags: javascript, validation, vuejs2

I am trying to validate the input type number. Let's take an example what I am facing in vuejs.

```
<input type="number" v-model="form.vat_id"/>
<!-- this is an error message for required -->
<p class="error" v-if="form.vat_id == ''">VAT ID is required</p>
<!-- this is an error message for invalid number -->
<p class="error" v-if="Number.isNaN(parseInt(form.vat_id)) && form.vat_id != ''">Please Enter Valid Number</p>
```

Now, it shows only one message of required one even if `form.vat_id` has invalid number. Here I tested that invalid number in vuejs is returning empty string but input showing the invalid number there in UI.Thus, I could not provide proper message here . What  should I do here.

If i remove `&& form.vat_id != ''` in second error message then both message were displayed in both condition - emtpy and invalid number

Comment: I see no mistake in your code. Maybe the problem is in the Javascript.

Comment: With the input type as "number" I don't think there's a way to enter non-number characters (without hacks). And empty string is considered a valid number, just like 0, hence the first required message would display.

Comment: If you really need to validate VAT numbers, please consider using [this component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-masked-input).

Comment: You can use v-if and v-else-if and check the vat_id on blur event on the input field and according to that show the messages.

Comment: @PulkitAggarwal yes but value is in empty string then else-if will never be executed because if statement is always true

Comment: @jom how can you prevent entering non-numeric character in html5 input type number... there is no need of hack.. it simply allowed to enter non-numeric character that's why I need to validate .. Using another component is not a proper solution

Comment: @VeshrajJoshi If you enter any character then `form.vat_id` must contains the some character and then else-if condition run.

Comment: @PulkitAggarwal that's what i am saying man... If i enter any non numeric character then v-model value becomes empty ... suppose - you entered `123456e` in inputbox then form.vat_id is giving empty string..

Comment: @VeshrajJoshi Please check my answer and check its working for you or not.

Comment: @VeshrajJoshi This appears to browser-specific quirks, if you add an input of type of number on **Chrome**, it will automatically prevent you from entering non-numeric characters, and it should! In fact, all browsers should. But Firefox does not seem to respect that. If you don't want to use component, how about [a directive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-inputmask)?

Answer (score 0):

You can take two more variables viz. vatError and vatErrorMsg with default values false and empty string respectively.

```
// In your template

   <input type="text" v-model="form.vat_id" @keyup="checkVatId"/>
   <p class="error" v-if="vatError">{{vatErrorMsg}}</p>

// Now define the method checkVatId

   checkVatId() {
      var vatIdRegex =  // here your vat_id regex.
      if (this.form.vat_id == ''){
        this.vatError = true;
        this.vatErrorMsg = "VAT ID is required.";
      } else if(!vatIdRegex.test(this.form.vat_id)) {
        // Run when user input is not matched with vat id regex.
        this.vatError = true;
        this.vatErrorMsg = "Please Enter Valid Number.";
      } else {
        this.vatError = false;
      }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's already done with input type text - existing code is working fine for input type text. So, i am looking for input type number - which can be useful to work with html5 and vuejs both.